# GLMM: glmer error when setting interaction terms

Tags: mixed-model, categorical-data, lme4-nlme, binomial-distribution, glmm

I am having difficulty fitting a generalized linear mixed-effects model in R.

I did a simple study looking at the variables affecting the triggering of camera traps. My response variable is binary (triggered/not triggered), and I have four categorical variables: camera sensitivity setting (low-normal-high), distance (5m-10m-15m-20m), time (day-night), and habitat (open-closed). I also would like to include the camera used as a random effect.

My data are structured like this with sensitivity, distance, habitat and time as factors:

```
Detection Sensitivity Camera_No Distance_m Habitat Time 
1           1         1          5          1       1 
1           2         2          5          1       1
1           3         3          5          1       1
0           1         1         10          1       1  
1           2         2         10          1       1  
1           3         3         10          1       1
```

Running this works:
`model1 <- glmer(Detection ~ Sensitivity + Distance_m + Habitat + Time + (1|Camera_No), data = df, family="binomial")`

However I am interested in the interaction between terms.
I get the below errors when I try:
`model2 <- glmer(Detection ~ Sensitivity * Distance_m * Habitat * Time + (1|Camera_No), data = df, family="binomial")`

```
Warning messages:
1: In (function (fn, par, lower = rep.int(-Inf, n), upper = rep.int(Inf,  :
  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
2: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, start, rho$lower, control = control,  :
  convergence code 4 from Nelder_Mead: failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
4: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues
```

I am newish to R and data analysis, and I haven't been able to find the answer from searching. I am probably doing something obviously wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that that model2 has too many parameters.

Comment: @utobi I have 2880 data points, is this not enough for the amount of parameters?

Comment: Do you have varying values of `Detection` for *every possible one of the 24 combinations* of the explanatory variables?  If not, then you will have trouble due to this "perfect separation."

Comment: @whuber there are 48 combinations of the variables (3 sensitivities x 4 distances x 2 habitats x 2 times) - I've just taken a look at the data and there are 14/48 instances were the detection is either all zeros or all ones (ex: high,5m,open,day: 60/60 detections, low,20m,closed,night: 0/60 detections) -- is there a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, I multiplied hastily.  You need a simpler model, because your data do not suffice to estimate the one you have chosen.  Perhaps the best approach is to choose a simplification that is theoretically meaningful, rather than using some kind of statistical approach to variable selection.